# How would one go about using JSDoc to document a function inside of a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am trying to document the function parameters `message` and `client` in my code for a discord bot. But I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Heres some example code that roughly follows what my code is:

```js
var discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
   name: "exampleCommand",
   aliases: ["example", "example2"],
   execute(message, client){
   message.channel.send("example")
   }
}
```

A few things I've tried:

```js
/*
 * Execute command
 * @param {discord.Message} message - The message that was sent
 * @param {discord.Client} client - The discord bot client
*/
execute(message, client){
message.channel.send("example")
}
}
```

I found this in a different question here, but that didn't do it either:

```js
/*
 * @param {name:string, aliases:Array, execute(discord.Message, discord.Client)}
*/
{
    name:"exampleCommand",
    aliases:["example", "example2"],
    execute(message, client){
    message.channel.send("example")
    }
}
```

I assume my IDE (Visual studio code) is supposed to auto-detect JSDoc comments and give the proper IntelliSense recommendations, but it just shows that their type is `any` still. What is the proper way to document this function inside of JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way simpler than I originally thought. I was starting my JSDOC comments incorrectly. I was starting them with `/*` when I should have been starting them with `/**`. This little fix made everything work as intended.